# Stripping spaces between XML nodes with Python

Tags: python, xml, xslt

Is there a easy way to accomplish the same thing in Python as xsl accomplishes with:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

So for instance in the following

```
for event, elem in ElementTree.iterparse("/tmp/example.xml"):
    if elem.tag == "example":
        print ElementTree.tostring(elem)
```

when the example nodes are printed out all the spaces and line feeds in the input file between children of the example node will be removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use the [lxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml) module, this becomes much easier. From [the lxml tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#parser-objects):

```
>>> parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True) # lxml.etree only!
>>> root = etree.XML("<root>  <a/>   <b>  </b>     </root>", parser)
>>> etree.tostring(root)
b'<root><a/><b>  </b></root>'
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to explicitly manipulate the subtree to strip every text and tail:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

for event, elem in ElementTree.iterparse("/tmp/example.xml"):
    if elem.tag == "example":
        subiter = ElementTree.ElementTree(elem).getiterator()
        for x in subiter:
          if x.text: x.text = x.text.strip()
          if x.tail: x.tail = x.tail.strip()
        print ElementTree.tostring(elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution could have an iterator which simply filters out whitespace-only text nodes:

```
import re

whitespaces = re.compile('\s*$')
def omit_whitespaces(iter):
    for event, elem in iter:
        if whitespaces.match(elem.text): elem.text = ''
        if whitespaces.match(elem.tail): elem.tail = ''
        yield event, elem

def strip_whitespaces(iter):
    for event, elem in iter:
        elem.text = elem.text.strip()
        elem.tail = elem.tail.strip()
        yield event, elem
```

And then use it as follows (either `strip` or `omit`, depending on whether you want to preserve spaces in text nodes with non-whitespace characters too):

```
for event, elem in omit_whitespaces(ElementTree.iterparse("/tmp/example.xml")):
    if elem.tag == "example":
        print ElementTree.tostring(elem)
```

Note that in this case you have to use only 'end' event (otherwise parser can give you partial data).

But... I don't really know ElementTree very well and I didn't tested this code though.